# How can I join the count in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, count

If I have two tables one is:

CAR

```
| ID |  MAKER |
---------------
|  1 |  Honda |
|  2 | Toyota |
|  3 |   Ford |
|  4 |  Honda |
|  5 |   Ford |
|  6 |  Honda |
```

where id is the car id number and maker is the maker of the car

and the other is

Purchase

```
| CUSTID | CARID |
------------------
|      1 |     1 |
|      1 |     4 |
|      1 |     6 |
|      2 |     1 |
|      2 |     2 |
|      2 |     4 |
|      2 |     6 |
|      3 |     2 |
|      4 |     5 |
|      4 |     2 |
```

where custid is the id of the customer and carid is the id to a specific car

Is there a way to join the two together and then figure out which customers have bought ALL the `Hondas`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this query:

```
select P.CustID
from purchase P
inner join CAR C on P.CarID=C.CarID
WHERE C.Maker like '%Honda%'
group by CustID
having count(P.CarID)=
    (select count(*) from CAR C where C.Maker like '%Honda%')
```

**[SQL FIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/3f21d/3)**

Comment: This is just a hypothetical list what if this wasn't a complete list?

Comment: @Luv - `LIKE` should not be used when we have specific name (e.g. Honda in this case). This won't give you expected result when we have `Maker` name [like HeroHonda](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9ed5/1)

Comment: @hims056 But **`HeroHonda`** is not a **`CAR Maker`**.

Comment: @Luv - Don't go to the real world I am just giving you an example.

Answer (score 1):

You need to join both tables with `CarID`, group it with `CustID` and need to use `HAVING` clause to get all records where CarID in 1,4,6. Here `3` in `HAVING` clause indicates numbers of CarIDs (i.e. 1,4 and 6).

```
SELECT P.CustID, COUNT(CarID)
  FROM Purchase P
  JOIN Car C
    ON P.Carid = C.ID
 WHERE CarID IN (1,4,6)
 GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(CarID) = 3;
```

Or instead of IDs use the name directly:

```
SELECT P.CustID, COUNT(CarID)
  FROM Purchase P
  JOIN Car C
    ON P.Carid = C.ID
 WHERE Maker = 'Honda'
 GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(CarID) = 3;
```

To get Count (e.g. 3 in this case)Use this query

```
SELECT COUNT(Maker) FROM Car WHERE Maker = 'Honda';
```

#### So you whole query can be like this:

```
SELECT P.CustID, COUNT(CarID)
  FROM Purchase P
  JOIN Car C
    ON P.Carid = C.ID
 WHERE Maker = 'Honda'
 GROUP BY CustID
HAVING COUNT(CarID) = (SELECT COUNT(Maker) FROM Car WHERE Maker = 'Honda');
```

Output:

```
╔════════╦══════════════╗
║ CUSTID ║ COUNT(CARID) ║
╠════════╬══════════════╣
║      1 ║            3 ║
║      2 ║            3 ║
╚════════╩══════════════╝
```

- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/16e0d/6)
- See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/a45191/20) with more values

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
SELECT A.*, B.*, C.* FROM purchase AS A
INNER JOIN(customer AS B) ON(A.cust_id = B.cust_id)
INNER JOIN(car AS C) ON(A.car_id = C.car_id)
WHERE A.car_id = '1'
```

I assume you have `customer` table. And remember that your `purchase` table must have an primary field like `purchase_id`. And `WHERE A.car_id = '1'` that's a clause that your Honda's ID is `1`